# Random variable independence characterization

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X,Y$ be two random variables I'm trying to prove that 
$$
X,Y\text{ are independent } \Leftrightarrow\; f_{XY}(x,y)=g_1(x)g_2(y)
$$
I've already done the $(\Rightarrow)$ part and got stuck in the other one:
So, letting $\;\;f_{XY}(x,y)=g_1(x)g_2(y)$ I want to prove that $X,Y$ are independent. Let $D_1,D_2\subseteq\Bbb R$ so
$$
\Bbb P(X\in D_1 , Y\in D_2)=\int_{D_2}\int_{D_1}f_{XY}(x,y)dxdy=\int_{D_2}\int_{D_1}g_1(x)g_2(y)dxdy=\int_{D_1}g_1(x)dx\int_{D_2}g_2(y)dy
$$
and got stuck here since I have not managed to show that $\int_{D_1}g_1(x)dx\int_{D_2}g_2(y)dy=\Bbb P(X\in D_1)\Bbb P(Y\in D_2)$ Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: **Hint:** Use the special case $D_2=\Bbb R$ to express $\Bbb P(X_1\in D_1)$ in terms of $g_1$ and $g_2$.

Comment: I see it now, thanks!